# Does MongoDB Panache support change streams?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

Does MongoDB Panache offer support for change streams? I cannot find any information about it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing specific inside MongoDB with Panache for change streams.

You can the underlying collection or database from your Panache entity/repository via the `collection()` or `database()` method. Then you can use the standard `watch()` method to define a change stream.